# Generate XML from Collection using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an entity as under

```
class DBDetails
    {
        public int ServerId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int DBId { get; set; }
        public string DbName { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

It is populated as under

```
List<DBDetails> lstDBDetails = new List<DBDetails>();
lstDBDetails.Add(new DBDetails { ServerId = 1, Title = "IISDevdb1", Address = "Address1", DBId = 1, DbName = "db1", UserId = "u1", Password = "p1" });
lstDBDetails.Add(new DBDetails { ServerId = 2, Title = "iis2", Address = "Address2", DBId = 2, DbName = "db2", UserId = "u2", Password = "p2" });
lstDBDetails.Add(new DBDetails { ServerId = 1, Title = "IISDevdb1", Address = "Address1", DBId = 3, DbName = "db3", UserId = "u3", Password = "p3" });
```

I need to generate the following xml from it

```
<DataBaseServers>
  <DataBaseServer id="1" title="IISDevdb1" address="Address1">
    <DataBases>      
      <database id="1" name="db1" userID="u1" password="p1" />
      <database id="3" name="db3" userID="u3" password="p3" />
    </DataBases>
  </DataBaseServer>
  <DataBaseServer id="2" title="iis2" address="Address2">
  <DataBases>      
      <database id="1" name="db2" userID="u2" password="p2" />    
    </DataBases>
</DataBaseServers>
```

How can I do so using XDocument?

My unsuccessful shot

```
var res = (from x in lstDBDetails
                       group x by x.ServerId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           A = g.Key ,
                           B = g.ToList()
                       });

            var doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("DataBaseServers",
                    res.Select(x =>
                        new XElement("DataBaseServer",
                             new XAttribute("id", x.A),                             
                                 new XElement("DataBases",
                                     x.B.Select(y =>
                                     new XElement("database",
                                         new XAttribute("id", y.DBId),
                                         new XAttribute("name", y.DbName),
                                         new XAttribute("userID", y.UserId),
                                         new XAttribute("password", y.Password))))))));
```

Comment: @Tommy Grovnes, I have updated with what i have tried so far..it is very close ...only thing is that i am not able to put the address and title

Comment: Is there anything wrong i asked for which i have been downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the probable reason is your original post just asked for code without providing any errors or what you have tried so far. Hence my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = (from x in lstDBDetails
                       group x by new { x.ServerId, x.Title,x.Address } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           ServerId = g.Key.ServerId,
                           Title = g.Key.Title,
                           Address = g.Key.Address,
                           B = g.ToList()
                       });

            var doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("DataBaseServers",
                    res.Select(x =>
                        new XElement("DataBaseServer",
                             new XAttribute("id", x.ServerId),
                             new XAttribute("title", x.Title),
                             new XAttribute("address", x.Address),
                                 new XElement("DataBases",
                                     x.B.Select(y =>
                                     new XElement("database",
                                         new XAttribute("id", y.DBId),
                                         new XAttribute("name", y.DbName),
                                         new XAttribute("userID", y.UserId),
                                         new XAttribute("password", y.Password))))))));
```